# Bluetooth Unable to start discovery after discovery failed

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, rfcomm

I have created a very simple application using `createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord` and `listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord` to learn how to use Android Bluetooth API.

I tested the app with two devices, A and B, device A is Lollipop and from LG, and device B is KitKat and from LG.

When device B can't find specified UUID when `connect()` is called, 'Service Discovery failed' is thrown. However, after once 'Service Discovery failed' is thrown, `connect()` called later would throw 'Unable to start Service Discovery' **immediately**. (checked with debugger)

The behavior is NOT fixed by terminating and restarting the app, and requires a reboot to be fixed. It seems other Bluetooth applications using insecure RFCOMM works, however. (tested with 'Bluetooth Terminal' application on Play Store)

Note: Device A is free from such behavior. Actually, it doesn't even throw 'Service Discovery failed' exception and throws that 'Socket is not opened' or something like that.

Here is my source code:

```
package com.example.bluetoothtest;

// Imports here

//Device A MAC: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
//Device B MAC: YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    UUID myUUID = UUID.fromString("ceceb700-28a8-11e7-9598-0800200c9a66"); //Random generated using a website
    BluetoothAdapter bl;
    BluetoothDevice remote;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        bl = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        remote = bl.getRemoteDevice("XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX");
    }

    public void onConnectAsServerClick(View v) {
        System.out.println("server");
        try {
            BluetoothServerSocket server_sock = bl.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord("bluetoothtest", myUUID);
            System.out.println("accepting");
            BluetoothSocket sock = server_sock.accept();
            System.out.println("accepted");
            System.out.println(Integer.toString(sock.getInputStream().read()));
            server_sock.close();
            sock.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void onConnectAsClientClick(View v) {
        System.out.println("client");
        try {
            BluetoothSocket sock = remote.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(myUUID);
            System.out.println("connecting");
            sock.connect(); // Exceptions thrown here
            System.out.println("connected");
            sock.getOutputStream().write(20);
            sock.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is log for 'Service Discovery failed' exception:

```
I/System.out: client
I/BluetoothSocket.cpp: Setting Master socket option
I/System.out: connecting
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Service discovery failed
W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket$SdpHelper.doSdp(BluetoothSocket.java:504)
W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:252)
W/System.err:     at ml.minary.example.MainActivity.onConnectAsClientClick(MainActivity.java:61)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
W/System.err:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4336)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17587)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5230)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:564)
W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And here is 'Unable to start Service Discovery':

```
I/System.out: client
I/BluetoothSocket.cpp: Setting Master socket option
I/System.out: connecting
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Unable to start Service Discovery
W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket$SdpHelper.doSdp(BluetoothSocket.java:494)
W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:252)
W/System.err:     at ml.minary.example.MainActivity.onConnectAsClientClick(MainActivity.java:61)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
W/System.err:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4336)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17587)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5230)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:564)
W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```